# Bash quotes syntax

Tags: bash

What does it do? Does it named "magic quotes"?

> `

(to type this use the key left of "1" on the keyboard)

Are the

> ``

expression is equivalent to

> $()

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are referring to is called **Command Substitution** and yes the two versions of the syntax are functionally identical, see [**HERE**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) for the POSIX spec.

Note that `$()` is favored over the backticks because it's much easier to read and it can nest within itself *much* easier than the backtick version.

As for what it does in, it essentially allows you to capture the output of a shell command in a variable. For example:

```
$ myDate=$(date); echo "Today's date is -->$myDate<--"
Today's date is -->Mon Mar 28 23:49:20 PDT 2011<--
```

Comment: thanks for the [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03)!

Comment: Or: `echo "Today's date is -->$(date)<---"`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

[Advanced Bash Scripting - Quoting](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quoting.html)

Comment: do yourself a favor and forget you ever saw the Advanced Bash Scripting site. Instead use [**THIS**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) as your goto place for `bash` tips & tricks